# Efficient join query in LINQ

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, linq

I am performing join operation in LINQ for two tables but it is taking most of the time to execute for small dataset. Following is the LINQ query

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++)
 {
      var test = from r1 in dtRowForNode.AsEnumerable()
                 join r2 in dtFileRowForNode.AsEnumerable()
                 on r1.Field<int>("Lng_Upload_Id") equals r2.Field<int>("Lng_Upload_Id")
                 where ((r1.Field<string>("Txt_Called_Number") == "999") || r1.Field<string>("Txt_Calling_Number") == "888")
                 select r2.Field<string>("Txt_File_Name");

       string[] str = test.Distinct().ToArray();                
}
```

Here i have two datatables `dtRowForNode` that has around 7500 Rows and other one is `dtFileRowForNode` that has only 12 Rows.

Now i going for looping this query for  200 times, it takes almost 6-7 seconds to complete the for loop. Why it is taking so much of time for such a small dataset.

Should i write this in different way ??

Comment: Do you really need the `AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: @MatthewWatson i could not get your point sir !!!

Comment: AsEnumerable() goes through every item and adds it to Enumerable variable

Comment: You might try putting the records into a strongly typed list instead of the loosely typed datatable.  I'm sure all the converting/unboxing is eating quite a bit of time.

Comment: @RajeevKumar I meant does it compile without it, or perhaps you need `AsQueryable()` instead (so that the query runs in the DB)

Comment: @MatthewWatson datatable does not have any method `AsQueryable()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following runs any faster for you:

```
var rowForNode=dtRowForNode.AsEnumerable().Select(dt=>new {
  Lng_Upload_Id=dt.Field<int>("Lng_Upload_Id"),
  Txt_Called_Number=dt.Field<string>("Txt_Called_Number"),
  Txt_Calling_Number=dt.Field<string>("Txt_Calling_Number")}).ToList();

var fileRowForNode=dtFileRowForNode.AsEnumberable().Select(dt=>new {
  Lng_Upload_Id=dt.Field<int>("Lng_Upload_Id"),
  Txt_File_Name=dt.Field<string>("Txt_File_Name")}).ToList();

 for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++)
 {
      var test = from r1 in rowForNode
                 join r2 in fileRowForNode
                 on r1.Lng_Upload_Id equals r2.Lng_Upload_Id
                 where (r1.Txt_Called_Number == "999"
                    || r1.Txt_Calling_Number == "888")
                 select r2.Txt_File_Name;

       string[] str = test.Distinct().ToArray();                
}
```

Comment: Then something is odd, because I just ran the same test, with some dummy data that has 7718 records in the first table, and 12 records in the second, and the entire thing takes 0.046 seconds.

Comment: I just added a .ToList() on the variable creations just to make sure LINQ isn't recreating them every loop.  My test data wasn't actually in a datatable, I created the outer variables directly.  That could be the difference.

Answer (score 0):

From where the data are coming into these two datatables.?? If it is coming from database then try to use IQueryable or IEnumerable or IList. These will be faster and also set LazyLoading option as False. First get the data into the var or IQueryable or IEnumerable or IList and then apply below query for join :

```
IQueryable<string> testList = (from p in dbContext.test
                             join c in dbContext.test1 on p.testId equals c.test1Id
                             select c.test1);
```

I hope it will help you. :)